# Display pdf on WebView

Tags: android, pdf, webview

How to display `.pdf` file inside android webview?

Comment: Add some 3rd party libraries and open inside your applocation

Comment: Check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814758/need-help-to-convert-a-pdf-page-into-bitmap-in-android-java/16294833#16294833

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437602/how-to-display-a-pdf-via-android-web-browser-without-downloading-first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this snipped:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView webView=new WebView(MainActivity.this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

    String pdfURL = "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37098169/Course%20Brochures/AND101.pdf";
    webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfURL);

    setContentView(webView);
}

private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            WebView view, String url) {
        return(false);
    }
}
```