# How to display a PDF via Android web browser without downloading the file

Tags: android, pdf

I have to display a pdf from URL.
When i directly open the url in a webview then it asks me to download the pdf and then view based on the app that i want to use to view it.
But I do not want to download the pdf, it must be just displayed directly.

Some answers that I went through on SO recommended to make use of docs.google.com

like here: [How to display a PDF via Android web browser without "downloading" first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437602/how-to-display-a-pdf-via-android-web-browser-without-downloading-first)

But this doesnt seem to be working anymore.

Comment: 'Doesnt seem to work' is not a very accurate description of your problem.

Comment: I think you are getting something wrong. To display the content of a .pdf, it always has to be downloaded first. What you want to achieve is to only temporarily download it, and delete it again after the user exited the .pdf viewer.

Comment: It just displays that preview not available. Even the older examples that I went through, at the time when google had introduced this, even those examples are now showing that preview not available.

Comment: @ZerO What i want is that the pdf must not be downloaded on the device. Earlier there have been solutions using google docs url, similar to the answer that I have shared in my question, but now that is not working.

Comment: The pdf is always loaded into a cache, and therefore downloaded.

Comment: how can we do that in cache, coz currently when I access the direct link in my webview of the app or even in the browser using intents, it is downloading it in the main memory i.e downloads.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=[url_pdf]

eg. webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://www.unipg.it/files/pagine/410/4-PDF-A.pdf");

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already tried this, and this is not working for me, I get the same output, "Preview not available".

Answer (score 0):

use this inside your body tags

```
    <iframe src="http://example.com/yourpdf" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none;">This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="http://example.com/yourpdf">Download PDF</a></iframe>
```