# Mobile App is not able to show a PDF that is stored on Web Server

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-mvc, mobile

My team works on a Mobile application, as well as a web application.  The mobile apps are about 80% web views that live on the web server.

We have a Help page that now requires a link to a PDF File that also lives on the Web server.

When I attempt to make the controller return File("pdflink.pdf","application/pdf") everything works fine on the iOS application.  When I try to use one of our Androids to hit the same link, the Android just shows a blank page and the PDF does not open.

I was wondering if anyone has ever had to create a mobile view on a web platform that was then called by mobile applications.

I have tried creating a view that used an iframe with the pdf in it, but that also did not work on either device (iOS/Android).

Any help with how to handle a web link to a pdf from mobile applications?

Comment: AFAIK iOS/Mobile Safari has build-in support while Android does not out of the box. Checkout [this Entry about a similar Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437602/how-to-display-a-pdf-via-android-web-browser-without-downloading-first). One Method may be to use [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) but it has [limits](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-browsers-are-supported) too.

Comment: Thank you @makadev.. we will look into that question/answer and see if any of those work for us.