# Android Chromium PDF Viewer Without File Download

Tags: android, pdf, chromium

I know this may be a long shot, but I'm building a fork of Android Chromium and trying to find a way to support viewing PDF files from external sites in-browser, without downloading the file.

It's a strict business rule that the PDFs cannot be stored on the device.

I've noticed that mobile Safari on iOS devices does something similar to this and shows the PDF in-browser.

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437602/how-to-display-a-pdf-via-android-web-browser-without-downloading-first) which is helpful, but does not necessarily help me with the fact that I do not control what the external site hosting the PDF does.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.