# viewing PDF in mobile browser with Github Pages

Tags: web, github, github-pages

I am using GitHub Pages to host my website. I have a PDF file that I want visitors to be able to open directly in a browser. it is working flawlessly in desktop browser but the PDF is getting downloaded in mobile browsers.

i tried iframe & embed tag but they also download the file in mobile browsers instead of displaying it

i want visitors to be able to view it online

PS 
i dont want to use dropbox,onedrive or google docs or drive for hosting PDF

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7437602/5987698) help?

Comment: that could work but, is there any other way ?