# How to open pdf files in webview in pdfactivity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, webview, android-pdf-api

Hello I'm developing app to open pdf files in webview in pdfactivity. I tried opening through intent its redirecting to system inbuilt apps but not pdfactivity.java.
find the code below,
I declared this in my webview activity,

```
 private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Uri uri = WebvActivity.this.getIntent().getData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                intent.putExtra(PdfActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "url");
                startActivity(intent);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
```

I'm using **PdfViewer.jar** library,
In README text it is mentioned use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebviewActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "PATH TO PDF GOES HERE");
     startActivity(intent);
```

How can I get URL of pdf files from the webpage in webview & load them in PdfActivity.
See below link for your reference,
https://sourceforge.net/p/andpdf/code/HEAD/tree/tag/Beta_0_1_11/AndroidPdfViewer/activitysrc/net/sf/andpdf/

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BINGO!! My issue resolved can open pdf directly using `BufferedInputStream`

I created two activity, First Activity to load all pdfs in webview. When user clicks the link of pdf, the `pdfurl` fetches the url as strings, passes strings to next activity.
**PdfActivity.java**

```
   final String pdfurl = view.getHitTestResult().getExtra();
         Intent intent = new Intent(PdfActivity.this,PdfViewer.class);
         intent.putExtra("PDFURL",pdfurl);
         startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity is PdfViewer, bateksc pdfviewer to load pdf from url, edited as above
**PdfViewer.java**

```
package ak.wp.meto.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import ak.wp.meto.R;

public class PdfViewer extends Activity {
    private TextView txt; // You can remove if you don't want this
    private PDFView pdf;
    String value = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_pdf);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            value = bundle.getString("PDFURL");
        }
        System.out.println("PRINT PDFVIEWER DATA" +value);
        pdf = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView); //github.barteksc
        txt = findViewById(R.id.txtPdf);
        String pdfUrl = value;
        try{
            new RetrievePdfStream().execute(pdfUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load Url :" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    class RetrievePdfStream extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {
        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
            return inputStream;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
            pdf.fromStream(inputStream).load();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you use external library @abhilash?

Comment: @gumuruh YES, com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link could be very helpful for you [How to display a PDF via Android web browser without "downloading" first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437602/how-to-display-a-pdf-via-android-web-browser-without-downloading-first/42525770)

You can open a pdf using Google Docs Viewer.